# Is there a way to know time on page for a single page?

Tags: google-analytics, page

Just like we see it on Audience->behavior->engagement->visit duration: 0-10seconds X people, 11-30s Y people, etc, but for a given page only. Not average time. Google analytics has the data since we can see that info for all the site... how to see it for a page?

Answer (score 3):

The average time on page is readily available by going to:

Content -> Overview. The Avg. Time on page is displayed and from there you can drill down into individual pages to see the avg time on each individual page.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, bounced visits do not report a time on page - the average time on page will be misreported as a result. Consider using the "Non-bounce traffic" advanced segment to get more reliable figures.

Comment: @danlefree - Good point.